# "kubectl get " cli response time too high on k8s cluster

Tags: kubectl

I had two small k8s cluster (one with flannel and one with calico).

Exact steps were used to install the two k8s cluster only difference being selection of Pod network at install time (one uses flannel one uses calico).

**Issue was that "kubectl get all" command had different response time** on both cluster. It takes roughly a min to respond on k8s with calico while k8s with flannel gave instant response.

**was sure the issue is not due to Pod network selection choice** as had no issues in spinning pods etc on both cluster both are working as expected.

**Time on flannel based k8s 0m0.167s**

```
$ time kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-6db489d4b7-h2mvv   1/1     Running   0          17m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   10d

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   1/1     1            1           17m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-6db489d4b7   1         1         1       17m

real    0m0.167s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.028s
```

**Time on calico based k8s cluster hangs and responds only after nearly a minute .. 0m59.294s**

```
$ time kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-6db489d4b7-b8c2g   1/1     Running   0          11m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   20m

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   1/1     1            1           11m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-6db489d4b7   1         1         1       11m

real    0m59.294s
user    0m0.316s
sys     0m0.072s
```

At cluster install time it was ensured to **ran below commands as regular user**

```
To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config



 $ ll .kube/config
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5455 Jan 23 10:17 .kube/config
```

I tried setting the kubeconfig env variable as

```
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
```

Still this did not fix the response time for kubectl command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending a lot of time in wrong direction it was identified that the `cache` and `http-cache` folder under `$HOME/.kube` were not having the correct chown permission.

Once **fixed the permissions** on those two folders **`(cache and http-cache)`** as well **under `$HOME/.kube` the `kubectl get` response time was back to normal**.

```
ubuntu@k8s-calico-master-1:~/.kube$ ll
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:17 ../
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 cache/
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5455 Jan 23 10:17 config
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 http-cache/

ubuntu@k8s-calico-master-1:~/.kube$ cd cache/
ubuntu@k8s-calico-master-1:~/.kube/cache$ ll
total 12
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 ../
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 discovery/


ubuntu@k8s-calico-master-1:~/.kube$ cd http-cache/
ubuntu@k8s-calico-master-1:~/.kube/http-cache$ ll
total 164
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 ../
drwxr-x--- 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 23 10:18 .diskv-temp/
-rw-rw---- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  813 Jan 23 10:18 f436dd33b3ceee24aa367363c323688e

ubuntu@k8s-calico-master-1:~/.kube/http-cache$ time kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-6db489d4b7-b8c2g   1/1     Running   0          52m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   61m

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   1/1     1            1           52m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-6db489d4b7   1         1         1       52m

real    0m0.104s
user    0m0.104s
sys     0m0.024s
```